# Reusable Gatsby Transformer Cloudinary Image dynamic image sources

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've installed "gatsby-transformer-cloudinary" to my gatsby website. I've implemented API integration and It can be fetched and I can see any single image on a page from Cloudinary. I just want to use this component dynamically and I need your help how do I used image name area as dynamically like props ((eg: "image"))?

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"

export default (props) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      image: file(name: { eq: "3144_xl-2015" }) {
        cloudinary: childCloudinaryAsset {
          fixed(width: 300) {
            ...CloudinaryAssetFixed
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
 

  return (
    <div className="image-example">
      <Image
        fixed={data.image.cloudinary.fixed}
        alt={props.alt}
        title={props.title}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [`staticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query) (or `useStaticQuery` hook, in the end it works exactly in the same way), since it's a limitation from it, you can't pass variables. From the documentation:

> `StaticQuery` does not accept variables (hence the name “static”), but
> can be used in any component, including pages

If you want to use a dynamic `<Img>` component from `gatsby-image` you will need to use a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/) and pass some kind of unique value (like a slug) and filter through it.